# Why does my Bootstrap site get "bigger" when copied?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Ok, I have a bootstrap site: http://prodatingassistant.com/
(notice the space around the logo and nav links)

I literally copy and paste the entire site on my server to work on it.  The copied site is here: http://www.dropshop.com/pda/

(notice everything is condensed into a smaller width area, this messes up almost every single large fonts placement.  and also notice for some reason the smaller text fonts have become slightly larger making them look like crap.

So what am I missing here?  Why does this happen?  I looked everywhere for what this is called and can't find it anywhere.  I'm sure the solution is super simple to fix.  Thanks in advance to any replies!!

Comment: Both sites share the entirely same widths and heights.

Comment: Not for me: http://www.dropshop.com/pda/images/problem.png

Comment: Do me a favor, go to both sites and hit `CTRL+0`. I fear you accidentally zoomed in. I am on Windows 10, Google Chrome without any problems.

Comment: Wow thanks!  that worked!!  I knew it was something stupid on my end haha

Comment: Don't worry. I'll put that as an answer so this can be marked as solved ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the site looks all fine on my end, I assume you accidentally zoomed in/out on either of the webpages causing different layouts.

Under Google Chrome, restore the default zoom level via `Ctrl + 0`.